# Weka Combining all attributes into one

Tags: csv, classification, weka

I have created a CSV file in Excel containing data with a number of categories. This input data looks like this when opened in notepad:

```
Top Left;Top Middle;Top Right;Middle Left;Middle Middle;Middle Right;Bottom Left;Bottom Middle;Bottom Right;X Wins
x;x;x;x;o;o;x;o;o;positive
x;x;x;x;o;o;o;x;o;positive
```

When I open this in *Weka*, only one attribute is created containing all of the shown attributes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I copied all the data into Word and on a whim changed all the semicolons to commas and saved it back in notepad. This solved the problem. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the default delimiter (called `fieldSeparator`) to `;` by ticking the *Invoke options dialog*.

[image: Invoke options dialog]

Please ignore the highlights on this one, it's from another answer.
[image: Object Editor]